# why can't i assign an element to a const in the chrome conole? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

when i type

> document.getElementById('formatstring_widget_formatstring_14');

in the chome console, then it returns:

"<div data-mendix-id=​"51_37_138" class=​"mx-name-formatString1 mx-link submenu-item page-nav-9" tabindex=​"0" id=​"formatstring_widget_formatstring_14" focusindex=​"0" widgetid=​"formatstring_widget_formatstring_14" style>​…​​"

when i try to assign it to a variable then it returnes 'undefined' why does this happen?

> const parent = document.getElementById('formatstring_widget_formatstring_14');
> undefined

document.getElementById('formatstring_widget_formatstring_14');

​…​​

Comment: because there is nothing to return... and "parent" is a bad variable name to use globally because of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent

Comment: The output is the result of the expression you type in. `6` if you typed in `3+3`. An assignment does not return any value, so `a = 2` returns undefined.

Comment: that is true,  thanks haha

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning it to the variable correctly.

If you type in `parent` in the console, it will show you the exact value assigned to `parent`.

The reason the assignment shows `undefined` is because the statement itself does not evaluate to anything. It doesn't have the "result" value.

```
> 3 + 3
> 6
> const a = 3;
> undefined
> a
> 3
```

Also, as another user mentioned `parent` is not a good variable name because [`window.parent` is taken](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent).